# integrating Jenkins with git

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration

while trying to integrate Jenkins to work with git, I configure the repository in the job configuration, and I don't seem to be able to authenticate the connection.

I'm not sure what credentials I should put.

I have an ssh key in ~/.ssh and the owner is the user jenkins, and the public key is in my git account settings
What are the credentials I should use? Which username should it be? The git username or the username on my machine which generated the ssh key?
[image: credentials]
[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your machine seems to be running a version of Git older than 1.7.4 (which is about five years old), hence why you're getting an error about the missing `git config --local` flag.

You won't be able to use the Git plugin with Jenkins unless you update that (or switch to the JGit implementation).

Follow the guide from GitHub on how to [generate an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/), and add the public key to your GitHub account.

Then you can add this as a credential to Jenkins:

- Type: SSH Username with private key
- Username: can be anything, as the SSH username is specified in the Git configuration

Easiest would be to use "Enter directly", and to paste in the private key that you generated.
(otherwise, you would need to ensure that your generated keys are moved to the Jenkins `~/.ssh` directory, or that the files are readable by the Jenkins user)

If you generated the key with a password (it's not mandatory to do so), you should enter that in the "Passphrase" field.